# 'tuple' object is not callable while reshaping training data using python

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, lstm

I have data csv file with three inputs names temperature, humidity, wind. Here I want to predict temperature value in every 60 minute using LSTM model.

Here I write the code to reshape the train . But I got an error `tuple' object is not callable`

My code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv' )
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
data.set_index('date', inplace=True)
data = data.values

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

train_size = int(len(data) * 0.67)
test_size = len(data) - train_size
train, test = data[0:train_size,:], data[train_size:len(data),:]

X = 1
n_out = 1

x,y=[],[]
start =0
data = train.reshape(train.shape(train.shape[0] ,3, train.shape[1]))
for _ in range(len(data)):
  in_end = start+X
  out_end= in_end + n_out
  if out_end < len(data):
    x_input = data[start:in_end]
    x.append(x_input)
    y.append(data[in_end:out_end,0])
start +=1

x = np.asanyarray(x)
y = np.asanyarray(y)
```

[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit?usp=drive_web&ouid=113105666949273151155)

Error:

> data = train.reshape(train.shape(train.shape[0] ,3, train.shape[1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit?usp=drive_web&ouid=113105666949273151155)))

Error image:
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Error:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind putting the error content, not the image? There are people who can't see the image content and your chance for finding a solution can be diminished.

Comment: Please, also provide the line from which you get the error. By the way, the error comes from the last line, namely `data = train.reshape(train.shape(train.shape[0] ,3, train.shape[1]))` where you've tried to call shape as a method while it is a tuple and you may want to use indexing operator, `[index]` instead of calling shape as a method.

Comment: @Vaalizaadeh Thank you for the fast reply. I understood what you are saying and here I editted my question and here what I am trying to do is x values are my inputs and y value is my output (temperature) y (t+1) . For that I wrote the code. I hope now you can understand my question.

Comment: @Vaalizaadeh I used the index operator also

Comment: Yes, I may made a mistake due to the dimensions of your tuple. First, print out this `train.shape`. This should give you a tuple which shows the rank of your tuple, the number of dimensions it contains. After that, use the indexing operator on `train itself and not after calling train.shape. Then you can pass it into the trainn.reshape. You've tried to mix multiple items in a singlle line and that has caused this subtlety. Seperate each step and print that to track what really is going wrong.

Comment: @Vaalizaadeh Yes I can understand what you are saying, But I am unable to write that code what you are saying. If you can help me to write the code it will really help me to complete my code.

Comment: The provided answer completely answers your issue. I wanted you to solve the problem by yourself, but a nice answer has been provided by our friends :)

Comment: @Vaalizaadeh I tried your method and our friend's method. Then It gave me this error "cannot reshape array of size 402 into shape (134,3,3)"

Comment: Try this: `(-1, 3, 3)` and print its shape. You are probably counting the dimensions incorrectly.

Comment: @Vaalizaadeh I tried it and gave ma an error. Then I tried your earlier methods and also the code that is providing by my friend and I tried again and again. Then I found the correct code for my  code. Thank you for helping me to solve this problem. Here I upoad the code below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `train.shape` is simply a tuple. So `train.shape(arguments)` doesn't make sense because `train.shape` is not callable (hence the error). Try to just replace that line by

```
data = train.reshape((train.shape[0], 3, train.shape[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I applied your code and it gave me this error " cannot reshape array of size 402 into shape (134,3,3)" here I paste the image of the error.

Comment: @bala I do not know the dimensions of your array train, and I don’t know to what you want to rescale them. I thought that your array train has the shape shape[0]xshape[1]x3, but that is not the case. You have to think of the compatible shape that you want (I can‘t do that for you because I don‘t know enough about the shape of train).

Comment: Ya I got it. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @bala You‘re welcome! I‘m glad to have helped.

Comment: By using your code and trying another method I found the correct code which is running . Noe my full code is working. I upload my code below. Once again thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

After Trying all the codes by providing my friends , I found the correct code for my code. Here I upload the code .
Thank you for helping me to solve my code.

```
data = train.reshape((train.shape[0], 1, train.shape[1]))
```